# list of attributes associated with every element of text file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file :

```
Name     Attribute
A         b1
B         b2
C         b3
B         b4
A         b5
C         b7
```

I want the output to be

```
Name    Attribute
A       (b1,b5)
B       (b2,b4)
C       (b3,b7)
```

Any python/pandas suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [301]: df.groupby('Name')['Attribute'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.tolist())).reset_index()
Out[301]:
  Name Attribute
0    A  (b1, b5)
1    B  (b2, b4)
2    C  (b3, b7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, No lambda:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Attribute'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why dictionaries were made:

```
myfile = open('yourfile.txt','r').readlines()
mydict = {}
for line in myfile[1:]:
    data = line.split()
    if data[0] in mydict:
        mydict[data[0]].append(data[1])
    else:
        mydict[data[0]] = [data[1]]
```